# Change text color in matplotlib table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How do I change text color from black to red in the following table produced by matplotlib? Code example is taken from [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjI1Z6s0cPtAhUU8uAKHTggBUEQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F32137396%2Fhow-do-i-plot-only-a-table-in-matplotlib&usg=AOvVaw0FzWTE5t8RVzkmuNmGXLTY)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# hide axes
fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('tight')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center')

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37554606/matplotlib-table-row-label-font-color-and-size Setting font properties iteratively should do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing text color in cells for a table generated with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610994/changing-text-color-in-cells-for-a-table-generated-with-matplotlib)